# Creating a surface plot of a function on the simplex (using PSTricks or TikZ?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pstricks

I'd like to create an exact surface plot of a function defined on the unit simplex {(x, y, z): x + y + z = 1}.  Here's a sketch of the figure I'd like to create.

[image]

I know about surface plots in `PSTricks` and `TikZ`, about barycentric coordinate systems in `TikZ`, and about `ternaryaxis` in `pgfplots`, but I don't see a way of combining them to produce what I want.  (My difficulty is not with the specific form of the function; I'll be happy with an answer that plots the function x.)

I'd like to say something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} % or some special type of axis
    \addplot3 {<f(x,y,z)>};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

where `f(x,y,z)` is the definition of my function.  Is something like that possible?

Comment: Could this be the answer to your question: http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/surface-plot-math/ ?

Comment: No---that's just a regular surface plot of a function of two variables.  I want to plot a function of three variables, not two, defined on the unit simplex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PGFPLOTS has a patching type called triangle

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot3
                [patch,patch type=triangle]
                coordinates { (0,0,0) (1,1,.1) (0,1,.2) };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Every three coordinates you give it, it will draw (fill) a triangle for you.

So the next step is to generate those coordinates:

```
\def\addtriangle#1{
    \xdef\trianglesbuffer{\trianglesbuffer #1}
}
\def\calculatecoordinate(#1,#2,#3)[#4]=\f(#5,#6){
        \pgfmathsetmacro#1{#5}
        \pgfmathsetmacro#2{#6}
        \pgfmathsetmacro#3{\f({(#5)},{(#6)})}
        \pgfmathsetmacro#4{\g({(#5)},{(#6)})}
}
\def\calculatetriangle#1{
    % #1 is +            #1 is -
    %         C                  B A  
    %          ◣                  ◥   
    %         A B                  C  
    \calculatecoordinate(\xa,\ya,\za)[\wa]=\f(\x,\y)
    \calculatecoordinate(\xb,\yb,\zb)[\wb]=\f(\x#11,\y)
    \calculatecoordinate(\xc,\yc,\zc)[\wc]=\f(\x,\y#11)
    \addtriangle{(\xa,\ya,\za)[\wa] (\xb,\yb,\zb)[\wb] (\xc,\yc,\zc)[\wc]}
}
\def\calculatetheplot{
    \foreach\x in{0,...,20}{
        \foreach\y in{0,...,20}{
            % check \x + \y + \z =1
            %       ◣
            %       ◣ ◣
            %       ◣ ◣ ◣
            \ifnum\numexpr\x+\y<20
                \calculatetriangle+
            \fi
            %       
            %        ◥
            %        ◥ ◥
            \ifnum\numexpr\x>0 \ifnum\numexpr\y>0 \ifnum\numexpr\x+\y<21
                \calculatetriangle-
            \fi\fi\fi
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \def\trianglesbuffer{} % initialize the buffer
        \def\f(#1,#2){#2*#2/20+2*sin(40*#1)} % we want to plot this function
        \def\g(#1,#2){sqrt((#1-20/3)^2+(#2-20/3)^2)} % with this point meta
        \calculatetheplot
        \edef\pgfmarshal{
            \noexpand\addplot3
                [patch,patch type=triangle,point meta=explicit]
                coordinates{\trianglesbuffer};
        }
        \pgfmarshal
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Next we want to change the coordinate to the unit simplex

```
\def\calculatecoordinate(#1,#2,#3)[#4]=\f(#5,#6){
        \pgfmathsetmacro#1{#5+\f({(#5)},{(#6)})}
        \pgfmathsetmacro#2{#6+\f({(#5)},{(#6)})}
        \pgfmathsetmacro#3{20-(#5)-(#6)+\f({(#5)},{(#6)})}
        \pgfmathsetmacro#4{\g({(#5)},{(#6)})}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,axis equal,view={80}{15}]
        \def\trianglesbuffer{} % clear the buffer
        \def\f(#1,#2){0} % we want to plot this function
        \def\g(#1,#2){0} % with this point meta
        \calculatetheplot
        \edef\pgfmarshal{
            \noexpand\addplot3
                [patch,patch type=triangle,mesh,point meta=explicit]
                coordinates{\trianglesbuffer};
        }
        \pgfmarshal
        \def\trianglesbuffer{} % clear the buffer
        \def\f(#1,#2){1+sin(20*#1)*cos(30*#2)} % we want to plot this function
        \def\g(#1,#2){\f({(#1)},{(#2)})} % with this point meta
        \calculatetheplot
        \edef\pgfmarshal{
            \noexpand\addplot3
                [patch,patch type=triangle,point meta=explicit]
                coordinates{\trianglesbuffer};
        }
        \pgfmarshal
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Spectacular!  I'd like the simplex to appear to be horizontal.  That is, I'd like the line from each corner of the simplex to the value of the function at that point to be vertical.  One way to do that is to put the `tikzpicture` in a `\rotatebox`.  For `view={60}{15}`, `\rotatebox{57.5}{\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}}` seems about right.  (a) Is there a better way of doing that?  (b) Why does 57.5 work (approximately) for `view={60}{15}`? (I suppose that is really a math question, not a TeX question.)  I'd also like, if possible, to remove the existing axes and add a vertical axis.

Comment: @MartinJ.Osborne (a) Usually `\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=57.5]`. (b) It is indeed math. A better way is `view={135}{-35}`. An even better way is to define `\calculatecoordinate`, `\f`, `\g` properly. (c) `\begin{axis}[hide axis]`.

Comment: Can any permissible pgf math expression be used in the definition of the function?  The surface resulting from `\def\f(#1,#2){#1 > 10 ? #1 : 10} ` doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: Try `(#1 > 10 ? #1 : 10)`. Notice that `\f` is more like an inline expansion rather than a real function. One must be careful of `-(#1-#2)` and `-#1-#2`.

Comment: I can't find any version of the definition of my function that does not generate a TeX error.  Is there a lower-level language I can use to reliably define the function?  I want `\def\f(#1,#2){(#1 > 10 ? 20*(#1/(40-#1)) : (#2 > 10 ? 20*(20-#2)/(40-#2) : (#1 + #2 < 10 ? 20*(#1 + #2)/(20 + #1 + #2) : 20/3)))}`.   The definition `\def\f(#1,#2){(#1 > 10 ? 20*(#1/(40-#1)) : (#2 > 10 ? (20*(20-#2)/40) : 20/3))} ` compiles without error, but changing `20*(20-#2)/40` to `20*(20-#2)/(40-#2)`, which is what I want, gives an error (even though `\def\f(#1,#2){20*(20-#2)/(40-#2)}` compiles without error).

Comment: @MartinJ.Osborne The problem is `\g`: I should have written `\def\g{\f({(#1)},{(#2)})}`. By the way, yes, there are `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55795/discussion-between-martin-j-osborne-and-symbol-1).

Comment: I have corrected the code in Symbol 1's answer to reflect the error pointed out in Symbol 1's last comment.