# How to draw a 3D plane, whose coordinates must also obey an inequality?

Tags: plot, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to plot the plane x+y+z=0 subject to the constraint x < y < z.

This should yield a triangular plane that extends out from the origin.

I don't understand how to render this in tikz-3dplot. Is there a better package to use? I would assume that this can be done in tikz somehow.

Comment: Do you want `pgfplots`?

Comment: I guess he first plot [in my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359483/51022) is a good starting point.

Comment: 3x<0 and 3z>0, but y is unconstrained.