# How to draw a triangular mesh (unstructured grid) of an arbitrary shape using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

I would like to draw a figure that looks like this one using Tikz:[image]

This one is adapted from a book and serve here as an example. It does not have to be with the exact same boundary curves because I will only use it to present some terms (like the ones we see on the picture). The context: it represents two domains: a solid and a fluid with different spatial discretizations, i.e., two spatial meshes or grids, in this case a triangular mesh (in my field, we call it an 'unstructured' mesh). My main question is: is it possible to automatically generate this unstructured mesh using Tikz (or any other LaTeX package) for an **arbitrary** boundary?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359483/51022?

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try, @Symbol1! I think this can be very useful if I import the points from an external mesh generator

Comment: Despite that, I think this can be done automatically. It would take some time.

Comment: Pick any 4 points on a circle or ellipse.  There are two different ways to create two triangles connecting them together.

Comment: A brute force approach would be to take every possibie pair of mesh points $n(n-1)/2$ and sort them by distance.  Start drawing lines from shortest to longest, throwing out any that intersect previously drawn lines.